# Django error: has no attribute 'ForeingKey'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

everyone! 
I jus start leaning Python and Django. Can somebody help me with this topic. I can't understand why it doesn't work:

```
    from django.db import models

    # Create your models here.
    class Topic(models.Model):
    """ Тема которую изучает ползователь"""
    text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    def __str__(self):
        """возвращает представление модели"""
        return self.text

   class Entry(models.Model):
   """ Информация изученная пользователем """
   topic = models.ForeingKey(Topic)
   text = models.TexField()
   date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

   class Meta:
     verbose_name_plural = 'entries'
""" Возвращает строковое представление модели"""
def __str__(self):
    return self.text[:50] + "..."
```

The result is:

> File "/Users/stepankurakin/pystudy/learning_log/learning_logs/models.py", line 14, in Entry
>       topic = models.ForeingKey(Topic)
>
> AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'ForeingKey'

How can i fix it?

Comment: You made a typo change `ForeingKey`to `ForeignKey`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should fix the typo as first thing, and try again: it's `ForeignKey`.

The error `AttributeError` is usually triggered when you are asking an attribute (in this case the class `ForeignKey`) to an object that doesn't have that attribute. If you commit an error in the spelling you will see this exception.

Comment: Ups. It works. thanks a lot. I'm  jus learning english too and don't notice the typo. Thanks!